# AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: pytorch

I have a seq2seq network (a class) which is trained without any problem. I have just a constructor and a forward function in that class.

During testing, I am loading the model states and trying to call a test function of which executes testing but getting the following error.

```
if model.config.model == 'LSTM':
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 237, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattr__(self, name)
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

What I am doing:

```
model = Sequence2Sequence(dictionary, embeddings_index, args.max_length, args)
if args.cuda:
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
helper.load_model_states(model, filename)
test(model, input_sentence)
```

When program attempts to execute the last line, it produces the above mentioned error. Any idea why it is not working?

`model.test` function:

```
if model.config.model == 'LSTM':
    encoder_hidden, encoder_cell = model.encoder.init_weights(batch_sentence.size(0))
    output, hidden = model.encoder(batch_sentence, (encoder_hidden, encoder_cell))
else:
    encoder_hidden = model.encoder.init_weights(batch_sentence.size(0))
    output, hidden = model.encoder(batch_sentence, encoder_hidden)

# rest of the code goes here...
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the full stacktrace information to here.

Comment: @PhilipTzou updated.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the full stacktrace? Why it starts with an "if"?

Comment: The function is long, so I just pasted the relevant portion.

Comment: PyTorch doesn't have a `Sequence2Sequence` class, so where does it come from?

Comment: The point is that `nn.model` does not have an attribute `config`, so I assume that `config` must be defined in the Sequence2Sequence class ...